# Extending an existing Plugin class results in Class not Found PHP Fatal Error

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create my own Plugin that extends an existing Plugin class.
I can extend the base class and everything is fine.
However, if I extend a existing Plugin class, I get a `Class not Found` error.

e.g.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin;

use Drupal\contrib_module\Plugin\ClassA;

class MyClass extends ClassA {
  public function implement() {}
}
```

The error I am getting would be
`Class 'Drupal\contrib_module\Plugin\ClassA' not found in /var/www/project/web/modules/custom/my_module/src/Plugin/MyClass.php on line 7`

Any Thoughts guys?

Comment: Well, the `use` statement must be wrong. What contrib module is it? and which class?

Comment: I was extending a CommerceShipping Plugin from the commerce_usps module.
I am pretty sure the use statement is correct..

Answer (score 0):

There is no D8 [commerce_usps](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_usps) module yet. I found a [development version on github](https://github.com/trobey/commerce_usps/blob/master/src/Plugin/Commerce/ShippingMethod/USPS.php), I pressume you're using this one.

The use statement uses the following structure `use [namespace]\[classname]`

So your use statement needs to be

```
use Drupal\commerce_usps\Plugin\Commerce\ShippingMethod\USPS

class ForExample extends USPS { ...
```